# Locally runnable VM to simulate Amazon EC2 host

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I'm currently managing an application hosted on the Amazon EC2 cloud.

I'm curious whether it's possible to get hold of a VM that would most closely mimic the Red Hat environments that one deploys to on Amazon EC2.

This VM would be runnable locally, say on a Windows box, via VirtualBox.

It would enable me to work in an environment that closely resembles the production environment, rather than having to login to EC2 and do everything over SSH.

Should I just go to http://www.redhat.com and try and find a VM or installation media from there?

Or is there something else I could do?

Comment: I found an operating system called [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/), which is supposed to replicate a lot of the functionality of Red Hat enterprise servers. Thinking of [downloading an image of CentOS](http://virtualboxes.org/images/centos/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import you own VM into Amazon EC2. If you do this, you can prepare your VM locally then upload it to Amazon.

More information about this feature of EC2 can be found at http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/